# PHP_SELF vs PATH_INFO vs SCRIPT_NAME vs REQUEST_URI

Tags: http, php, codeigniter

I am building a PHP application in CodeIgniter. CodeIgniter sends all requests to the main controller: `index.php`. However, I don't like to see `index.php` in the URI. For example, `http://www.example.com/faq/whatever` will route to `http://www.example.com/index.php/faq/whatever`. I need a reliable way for a script to know what it's address is, so it will know what to do with the navigation. I've used `mod_rewrite`, as per CodeIgniter documentation.

The rule is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|inc|favicon\.ico|index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Normally, I would just check `php_self`, but in this case it's always `index.php`. I can get it from `REQUEST_URI`, `PATH_INFO`, etc., but I'm trying to decide which will be most reliable. Does anyone know (or know where to find) the real difference between `PHP_SELF`, `PATH_INFO`, `SCRIPT_NAME`, and `REQUEST_URI`? Thanks for your help!

**Note**: I've had to add spaces, as SO sees the underscore, and makes it italic for some reason.

**Updated**: Fixed the spaces.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The [PHP documentation](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) can tell you the difference:

> *'PHP_SELF'*

> > The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root. For instance, *$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']* in a script at the address *http://example.com/test.php/foo.bar* would be */test.php/foo.bar*. The [__FILE__](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file. If PHP is running as a command-line processor this variable contains the script name since PHP 4.3.0. Previously it was not available.

> *'SCRIPT_NAME'*

> > Contains the current script's path. This is useful for pages which need to point to themselves. The [__FILE__](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file.

> *'REQUEST_URI'*

> > The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, *'/index.html'*.

> *'PATH_INFO'*

> > Contains any client-provided pathname information trailing the actual script filename but preceding the query string, if available. For instance, if the current script was accessed via the URI http://www.example.com/php/path_info.php/some/stuff?foo=bar, then *$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']* would contain */some/stuff*.

Comment: This is most likely not about the PHP documentation but the CGI :) And there PATH_INFO is documented: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875#section-4 But there are some known issues that Apache and nginx are not always giving this variable.

Comment: Odin's answer below adds useful explanations that are complemented with examples. I find it hard to understand what these variables represent in a general context with a path_info, a query string, some redirection, some  aliases, on different operating systems, from CLI vs SERVER, etc.

Comment: -1 Just as an explanation as to why I downvoted: the entire reason I came to this post is because the documentation is not clear. Odin's answer below provides a clear explanation of the differences between these variables. I feel like it's an insufficient answer to just copy and paste easily found yet also insufficient documentation. I believe most people would have had to already visit the documentation to even know about the list of elements in the $_SERVER variable mentioned above.

Answer (score 255):

Some practical examples of the differences between these variables:
Example 1.
PHP_SELF is different from SCRIPT_NAME *only* when requested url is in form:
http://example.com/test.php/foo/bar

```
[PHP_SELF] => /test.php/foo/bar
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /test.php
```

(this seems to be the only case when PATH_INFO contains sensible information [PATH_INFO] => /foo/bar)
Note: this used to be different in some older PHP versions (<= 5.0 ?).

Example 2.
REQUEST_URI is different from SCRIPT_NAME when a non-empty query string is entered:
http://example.com/test.php?foo=bar

```
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /test.php
[REQUEST_URI] => /test.php?foo=bar
```

Example 3.
REQUEST_URI is different from SCRIPT_NAME when server-side redirecton is in effect (for example mod_rewrite on apache):

http://example.com/test.php

```
[REQUEST_URI] => /test.php
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /test2.php
```

Example 4.
REQUEST_URI is different from SCRIPT_NAME when handling HTTP errors with scripts.
Using apache directive ErrorDocument 404 /404error.php
http://example.com/test.php

```
[REQUEST_URI] => /test.php
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /404error.php
```

On IIS server using custom error pages
http://example.com/test.php

```
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /404error.php
[REQUEST_URI] => /404error.php?404;http://example.com/test.php
```

Comment: +1, "An example is not a way to learn, it's the only way to learn." - I always have to recheck this stuff, very nice research on the 404 errors. =)

Comment: +1: 1st time in my life I understood the difference. They should update PHP documentaion with your answer

Comment: Example1: [SCRIPT_NAME] => /test.php/ 
There should be no "/" at the end:
Example1: [SCRIPT_NAME] => /test.php 
Anyway that's what I see in PHP 5.3.6 .
Nice examples.

Comment: You are correct JohnM2, i have now checked on PHP 5.4 and the result for URL /pinfo.php/first/second?third=fourth is as follows:
QUERY_STRING => third=fourth
REQUEST_URI => /pinfo.php/first/second?third=fourth
SCRIPT_NAME => /pinfo.php
PATH_INFO => /first/second

Comment: I've tested this on 5.2.17 too and there's no `/` at the end of the `SCRIPT_NAME`. This seems to be consistent in PHP 5.2-5.4 then, considering editing the answer to reflect that.

Comment: You missed off `REQUEST_URI` vs `PHP_SELF` here they differ if you request http://example.com/ : `[REQUEST_URI] => /` and `[PHP_SELF] => /index.php`

Comment: This is very helpful especially the Example 4 error handling part. Recently I find that some programmers are using `REQUEST_URI` as conditions, then provide different header/footer respectively. It works in most cases but will have problems with 404/403 pages. I think a better way is to use `SCRIPT_NAME` to get the REAL requested page on Apache.

Comment: I know that it is not part of the question, but it is useful to mention that `[REQUEST_URI]` is defined before URL rewriting, including mod_dir rewrite as pointed out by @icc97. `[PHP_SELF] = [SCRIPT_NAME] + [PATH_INFO]` is defined after mod_dir and mod_rewrite, but before aliases are resolved. Aliases can change the complete URL path (which PHP names `[PHP_SELF]`) to obtain the `[SCRIPT_FILENAME]`, which is the actual script on the file system. To be slightly more complete, let's add that the script can include other files and `__FILE__` is the current file.

Comment: Example 1 also says that `[REQUEST_URI]` is different from  `[SCRIPT_NAME]`  when `[PATH_INFO]` is not empty.  It was understood, but it was not explicitly written. Example
   `[REQUEST_URI] => /test.php/foo.bar,  [SCRIPT_NAME] => /test.php`

Comment: worth noting this apache bug:  https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40102

Comment: Also worth putting in an example of domain traversal, as they differ in this way as well. For instance in `http://example.com/something/../test.php`, the REQUEST_URI will be `/something/../test.php` and the SCRIPT_NAME will be `/test.php`. :)

Answer (score 27):

`PATH_INFO` is only available when using htaccess like this:

### Example 1

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

#### Remains the same

```
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
```

#### Root

http://domain.com/

```
[PHP_SELF]     => /index.php
[PATH_INFO] IS NOT AVAILABLE (fallback to REQUEST_URI in your script)
[REQUEST_URI]  => /
[QUERY_STRING] =>
```

#### Path

http://domain.com/test

```
[PHP_SELF]     => /index.php/test
[PATH_INFO]    => /test
[REQUEST_URI]  => /test
[QUERY_STRING] =>
```

#### Query String

http://domain.com/test?123

```
[PHP_SELF]     => /index.php/test
[PATH_INFO]    => /test
[REQUEST_URI]  => /test?123
[QUERY_STRING] => 123
```

### Example 2

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### Remains the same

```
[SCRIPT_NAME]  => /index.php
[PHP_SELF]     => /index.php
[PATH_INFO] IS NOT AVAILABLE (fallback to REQUEST_URI in your script)
```

#### Root

http://domain.com/

```
[REQUEST_URI]  => /
[QUERY_STRING] =>
```

#### Path

http://domain.com/test

```
[REQUEST_URI]  => /test
[QUERY_STRING] => url=test
```

#### Query String

http://domain.com/test?123

```
[REQUEST_URI]  => /test?123
[QUERY_STRING] => url=test&123
```

### Example 3

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(([a-z]{2})|(([a-z]{2})/)?(.*))$ index.php/$5 [NC,L,E=LANGUAGE:$2$4]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})(/(.*))?$ $3 [NC,L,E=LANGUAGE:$1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

#### Remains the same

```
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
```

#### Root

http://domain.com/

```
[PHP_SELF]          => /index.php
[PATH_INFO] IS NOT AVAILABLE (fallback to REQUEST_URI in your script)
[REQUEST_URI]       => /
[QUERY_STRING]      => 
[REDIRECT_LANGUAGE] IS NOT AVAILABLE
```

#### Path

http://domain.com/test

```
[PHP_SELF]          => /index.php/test
[PATH_INFO]         => /test
[REQUEST_URI]       => /test
[QUERY_STRING]      => 
[REDIRECT_LANGUAGE] =>
```

#### Language

http://domain.com/en

```
[PHP_SELF]          => /index.php/
[PATH_INFO]         => /
[REQUEST_URI]       => /en
[QUERY_STRING]      => 
[REDIRECT_LANGUAGE] => en
```

#### Language path

http://domain.com/en/test

```
[PHP_SELF]          => /index.php/test
[PATH_INFO]         => /test
[REQUEST_URI]       => /en/test
[REDIRECT_LANGUAGE] => en
```

#### Language Query string

http://domain.com/en/test?123

```
[PHP_SELF]          => /index.php/test
[PATH_INFO]         => /test
[REQUEST_URI]       => /en/test?123
[QUERY_STRING]      => 123
[REDIRECT_LANGUAGE] => en
```

Comment: This answer is written in a way that suggests that only url rewritting can create a path_info, but, of course, the path info can be entered directly in the original URL.

Answer (score 17):

#### PHP Paths

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`       = Web path, requested URI
    `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`          = Web path, requested file + path info
    `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`       = Web path, requested file
    `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`   = File path, requested file
    `__FILE__`                      = File path, current file

#### Where

- **File path** is a *system file path* like `/var/www/index.php`, after alias resolution
- **Web path** is a *server document path* like `/index.php` from
  `http://foo.com/index.php`, and may not even match any file
- **Current file** means *the included script file*, not any script that includes it
- **Requested file** means *the includer script file*, not the included one
- **URI** is the *HTTP request* like `/index.php?foo=bar`, before any URL rewriting
- **Path info** is any extra Apache data located after the script name but before the query string

#### Order of Operation

1. Client sends server an *HTTP request* `REQUEST_URI`
2. Server performs any *URL rewriting* from .htaccess files, etc. to get `PHP_SELF`
3. Server separates `PHP_SELF` into `SCRIPT_FILENAME` + `PATH_INFO`
4. Server performs *alias resolution* and converts the entire *url path* to a *system file path* to get `SCRIPT_FILENAME`
5. Resulting script file may include others, where `__FILE__` refers to the path to the current file

Comment: This is good. Here are my comments.  First, both $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']  and $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] are script name,  except that the later is after aliases are executed.  Second, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] is not the script, but the script + the path info.  Again,  $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] is the script (before aliases).  Finally, it is useful to know at what stage, after or before rewrite-rules, after or before aliases, these variables are defined. See my answer.

Comment: @Dominic108 I revised my answer based on your suggestions, tidied things up a bit, and added an Order of Operation section. Let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: In your order, you have to swap `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` and  `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` , because mod_rewrite create the entire path, which is `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` .  The separation occurs next.  Note that aliases also consider the entire path to define the script filename, but the separation that defined script_name and path_info already occurred, so they will not be affected.

Comment: @Dominic108 I revised my answer again. For some reason your edit proposal was rejected, though as far as I know, you are correct that two of my items were out of order. I'm not as familiar with aliases, so I'm relying on your expertise for that part. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look into the [URI Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) and make use of $this->uri->uri_string()

Returns a string with the complete URI.

For example, if this is your full URL:

```
http://example.com/index.php/news/local/345
```

The function would return this:

```
/news/local/345
```

Or you could make use of the segments to drill down specific areas without having to come up with parsing/regex values

Comment: Thank you - this is a good idea, but I am using these in a pre-system hook that will need to run before the controller is up and running.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I use the `$REQUEST_URI` as it references the URI entered and not the location on the server's disc.

Comment: Is it always the complete URI?

Comment: Typically, you can run into issues with apache on windows, but it's only for URI's that don't resolve.

Answer (score 4):

There is very little to add to Odin's answer. I just felt to provide a complete example from the HTTP request to the actual file on the file system to illustrate the effects of URL rewriting and aliases. On the file system the script `/var/www/test/php/script.php` is

```
<?php
include ("script_included.php")
?>
```

where `/var/www/test/php/script_included.php` is

```
<?php
echo "REQUEST_URI: " .  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "<br>"; 
echo "PHP_SELF: " .  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "<br>";
echo "QUERY_STRING: " .  $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . "<br>";
echo "SCRIPT_NAME: " .  $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . "<br>";
echo "PATH_INFO: " .  $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] . "<br>";
echo "SCRIPT_FILENAME: " . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] . "<br>";
echo "__FILE__ : " . __FILE__ . "<br>";  
?>
```

and  `/var/www/test/.htaccess`  is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule before_rewrite/script.php/path/(.*) after_rewrite/script.php/path/$1
```

and the Apache configuration file includes the alias

```
Alias /test/after_rewrite/ /var/www/test/php/
```

and the http request is

```
www.example.com/test/before_rewrite/script.php/path/info?q=helloword
```

The output will be

```
REQUEST_URI: /test/before_rewrite/script.php/path/info?q=helloword
PHP_SELF: /test/after_rewrite/script.php/path/info
QUERY_STRING: q=helloword
SCRIPT_NAME: /test/after_rewrite/script.php
PATH_INFO: /path/info
SCRIPT_FILENAME: /var/www/test/php/script.php
__FILE__ : /var/www/test/php/script_included.php
```

The following always holds

```
PHP_SELF = SCRIPT_NAME + PATH_INFO = full url path between domain and query string.
```

If there is no mod_rewrite, mod_dir, ErrorDocument rewrite or any form of URL rewriting, we also have

```
REQUEST_URI = PHP_SELF + ? + QUERY_STRING
```

The aliases affect the system file paths `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and `__FILE__`, not the URL paths, which are defined before - see exceptions below. Aliases might use the entire URL path, including `PATH_INFO`. There could be no connection at all between `SCRIPT_NAME` and `SCRIPT_FILENAME` .

It is not totally exact that aliases are not resolved at the time the URL path `[PHP_SELF] = [SCRIPT_NAME] + [PATH_INFO]`  is defined, because aliases are considered to search the file system and we know from example 4 in Odin's answer that the file system is searched to determine if the file exists, but this is only relevant when the file is not found. Similarly, mod_dir calls mod_alias to search the file system, but this is only relevant if you have an alias such as `Alias \index.php \var\www\index.php` and the request uri is a directory.

Comment: Hi Dominic108, thanks for the revision. I do think it's useful to include the rewrite info. To me it was implied, but to others it may not be that intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever forget which variables do what, you can write a little script that uses [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) and call it from a URL with a query string. Since server software installations present the variables that PHP returns it's always a good idea to check the machine's output in case rewrites at the server config file are causing different results than expected. Save it as something like `_inf0.php`:

```
<?php
    $my_ip = '0.0.0.0';

   if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']==$my_ip){
     phpinfo();
   } else {
     //something
   }
```

Then you would call `/_inf0.php?q=500`

Answer (score 0):

## easy peasy simple answer:

assume `scheme://host/path/script.php`
after `script.php` there will be two possiblitiy:

1- *query string* like `scheme://host/path/script.php?qs=a`

2- *more path* info like `scheme://host/path/script.php/more/path`

---

now we have a very simple rules:

| property | what is included | e.g.: `http://localhost/dashboard/paln5/st1.php/a/b?c=d` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| REQUEST_URI | **everything** afterward is included | `/dashboard/paln5/st1.php/a/b?c=d` |
| PHP_SELF | **just *more path*** included | `/dashboard/paln5/st1.php/a/b` |
| SCRIPT_NAME | **nothing** afterward is included | `/dashboard/paln5/st1.php` |

Answer (score -1):

Backup a second, you've taken the wrong approach to begin with. Why not just do this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|inc|favicon\.ico|index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

instead? Then grab it with `$_GET['url'];`

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  This data is much more easily accessed!

Comment: And there is additional complexity if the original request is expected to have a query string. In its current state, the above code will simply overwrite the query string. If you merge query strings (`QSA` flag) then query string params can potentially be overwritten (for instance, if you needed a `url` param on the initial request) or worse, be vulnerable to XSS attacks.