# How to link to the current PHP file

Tags: php, hyperlink

I am writing a PHP file but I don't know what is the best way to create a link while the link is in the same file but with a different ID.  What I mean is that I have a file named `test.php` and it contains something like:

```
if ($id == "") {
    echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=test'>Try the test page</a>";
} else if ($id == "test") {
    echo "Here is the testing content with various information!";
}
```

I want to know what is better for more secure code:
`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?id=test` or `test.php?id=test`.

I know it serves the same purpose now, but if I change the file name `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?id=test` seems better because it will still point to the same file.

But I would like to know for sure which is safer.

Comment: Why not just use `?id=test` (without any page) if you're trying to link to the current one?

Comment: Echoing $_SERVER[*] is subject to XSS (cross site scripting).  However, you can encode it to protect against that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be printing `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`; it's a security vulnerability (there's an example here: [How To Identify The Requested Page In PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980018/how-to-identify-the-requested-page-in-php)).

If you're trying to link to the same page, but with query parameters (`?`) or anchors (`#`) you can simply link directly to them, as @kingkero suggests.

```html
<!--
  The code snippet runs as an iframe from http://stacksnippets.net/js, 
  so that's the root of the links you'll see if you click "Run".
-->
<a href="">Link to current page</a><br />
<a href="?id=test">Add query param to current page</a><br />
<a href="#anchor">Add anchor tag to current page</a>
```

Links that don't begin with a `/` or a protocol (like `http://`) are relative to the current document's location.  Links that begin with a `/` are relative to the domain root.  The behavior is laid out by the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html).

Broadly speaking, you're right, you should avoid hard coding things like the filename into your file.  But you also should generally not need to use data in `$_SERVER` to construct links.

Comment: So, the more easier way to use is just `?id=test` without the same file name, I'm right?

Comment: That's right.  You could try this yourself, just create a plain HTML file and create a link like my example.  Open the file in a browser, and you'll see clicking the link adds the query param.