# How to populate SCRIPT_FILENAME and SCRIPT_PATH server vairables to php-cgi from the command line

Tags: php, cgi, freebsd, php-5.5

I'm trying to run cron php script from command line. The server does not have PHP CLI but php-cgi exists. I tried to pass PHP directly to php-cgi but this does not work because two server environment variables are missed (`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_PATH']`). I tried to fill variables using [following recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7047581/) but these variables are not populated. What is missed in this answer? How to make php-cgi populate these server values? The question is not platform specific, but execution script looks like this currently

```
#!/bin/bash

export REDIRECT_STATUS=200
export GATEWAY_INTERFACE="CGI/1.1"
export SCRIPT_FILENAME=/usr/local/www/owncloud/cron.php
export REQUEST_METHOD="GET"

/usr/local/bin/php-cgi
```

Please note that I'm not asking for workaround, I already added helper php file which fill necessary values. But this is temporary solution because next software update could show another issue with php-cgi call

**UPDATE**

It seems the issue is not with php-cgi execution but with the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and `SCRIPT_PATH` server variables only. So [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7047581/) works in common cases when you do not need them. Also the issue might be version specific (it works with PHP version prior to 5.5) or platform specific

Comment: do you require the additional `export GATEWAY_INTERFACE` line?

Comment: have you tried `setenv` instead of `export`?

Comment: no, it was mistake in the code. But it does not affect the php-cgi behavior. export is bash equivalent of setenv. And setenv command does not exist for bash

Comment: what you are doing is correct, tested and it works for me. have you checked if you have got sufficient permission?

Comment: Do you check your php can access mentioned variable? Is it filled with correct path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched SO with question to these specific server variables and found following statement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1916146/):

> You are just juggling variables now. SCRIPT_FILENAME is a part of the
>   CGI spec. It will not be available if PATH_INFO is unavailable. As for
>   REQUEST_URI, it's apache's mod_rewrite specific. – LiraNuna

So exporting `PATH_INFO` variable also populates values from `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and `SCRIPT_PATH` environment variables. Please note that `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is needed still to point php-cgi to php input file. Below is the final script

```
#!/bin/bash

export REDIRECT_STATUS=200
export GATEWAY_INTERFACE="CGI/1.1"
export REQUEST_METHOD="GET"
export SCRIPT_FILENAME=/usr/local/www/owncloud/cron.php
export SCRIPT_PATH=cron.php
export PATH_INFO=$SCRIPT_FILENAME

/usr/local/bin/php-cgi
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i tested. i used root account on my home PC. My IP is masked from the output. cannot post this much as comment so posting as answer.

**The script**

```
#!/bin/bash

export REDIRECT_STATUS=200
export GATEWAY_INTERFACE="CGI/1.1"
export SCRIPT_FILENAME=/root/t.php
export REQUEST_METHOD="GET"

/usr/bin/php-cgi
```

**PHP file**

```
<?php
print_r($_SERVER);
?>
```

**Output I get**

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8
Content-type: text/html

Array
(
    [HOSTNAME] => HomePC
    [SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED] =>
    [SHELL] => /bin/bash
    [TERM] => xterm
    [HISTSIZE] => 1000
    [SSH_CLIENT] => xx.xx.xx.xx 58196 22
    [SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE] =>
    [SSH_TTY] => /dev/pts/3
    [USER] => root
    [LS_COLORS] => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /root/t.php
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
    [MAIL] => /var/spool/mail/root
    [PWD] => /root
    [LANG] => en_US.UTF-8
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED] =>
    [HISTCONTROL] => ignoredups
    [HOME] => /root
    [SHLVL] => 2
    [LOGNAME] => root
    [SSH_CONNECTION] => xxx.xxx.xx.xxx 58196 192.168.1.2 22
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [LESSOPEN] => ||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [G_BROKEN_FILENAMES] => 1
    [_] => /usr/bin/php-cgi
    [PHP_SELF] =>
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1379952948
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately if does not work for me. Also I do not see SCRIPT_NAME server variable in your output. It is also required by cron script

Comment: I think if you execute through CLI you get only `SCRIPT_FILENAME` http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php isn't `SCRIPT_FILENAME` good enough for your case?

Comment: cron.php fails with missed `SCRIPT_NAME` variable as well. Anyway I do not see `SCRIPT_FILENAME` in server variables as well. It could be PHP version specific, but I use newer version of PHP (`X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.2`)

Comment: if you really want `SCRIPT_NAME` you can add `export SCRIPT_NAME=/root/t.php`. This also fills the `PHP_SELF` variable.

Comment: May be version specific. I cannot have access to PHP 5.5.x now. can check tomorrow morning my time.

Comment: I tested this in `fc18 PHP 5.4.19` and works for me. 5.4.19 is the latest version available for my distro (don't want to compile from source). Sry I may not be able to help further.

Comment: Thank you anyway. It seems I found the reason of such behavior

Comment: Please post what you have found as an answer and accept it. It may help someone