# what's the difference between SCRIPT_FILENAME and SCRIPT_NAME?

Tags: php, global-variables

I tried to search for a difference but each time the vars are identical, any ideas ?

Comment: Better answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279966/php-self-vs-path-info-vs-script-name-vs-request-uri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Based on my understanding of this, they can be different if you're executing through the command line (CLI).

Comment: oh! ok then they are identical in 99.9% of my programming, thanks.

Comment: @Asaf `SCRIPT_FILENAME` should contain an _absolute_ path, whereas `SCRIPT_NAME` is document root-relative, so they should be different is most web hosting environments, not "identical"? However, they can also refer to different files entirely if using an Apache `Alias`. In this case `SCRIPT_FILENAME` refers to the file being directed to, whereas `SCRIPT_NAME` appears to report the URL/file you are requesting.

Answer (score 1):

Check THIS Difference:

- script_filename returns **REAL DIR**
  C:/xampp/htdocs/demo/index.php
- file returns **LOGIC JUNKTION**
  D:\www\local\demo\cms\init.php

Hold that in mind when checking pathes

Comment: Do you mean NTFS junction point?