# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] not returning the servername

Tags: php, apache2

recently i came across strange problem while uploading files to my new server.

I am using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to find the current page location and add some param and redirect as following:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&action=edit&uin=1';?>">Edit</a>
```

It works fine in my local computer and redirects to my page :

```
localhost/admin/home.php?module=Pages&action=edit&uin=1
```

and my tag:

```
<a href="http://localhost/sitename/admin/home.php?module=Pages&action=edit&uin=1">Edit</a>
```

but in my testing server it generated url without servername so it became like:

```
<a href="http://admin/home.php?module=Pages&action=edit&uin=1">Edit</a>
```

and redirected to : `http://admin/home.php?module=Pages&action=edit&uin=1` resulting redirect to invalid page...

So wondering which server setting is creating that difference?

And how can we solve it? both resulting same

Comment: The proxy in front of the PHP engine.

Comment: didn't get you? so how can we solve it? resulting same

Comment: According to your example $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] has `"http://admin/home.php?module=Pages"`

Comment: yeah it returns the same as you said but in local it becomes <a href="http://admin/home.php?module=Pages&action=edit&uin=1"> but in server <a href="http://admin/home.php?module=Pages&action=edit&uin=1">Edit</a>

Comment: read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279966/php-self-vs-path-info-vs-script-name-vs-request-uri)

Comment: The name *REQUEST\_URI* might be misleading as it does only contain the URI path and query as requested in the [HTTP request line](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5.1). So I doubt that your code does actually print the full URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP documentation can tell you the difference:

#### 'PHP_SELF'

> The filename of the currently
> executing script, relative to the
> document root. For instance,
> $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a script at
> the address
> http://example.com/test.php/foo.bar
> would be /test.php/foo.bar. The
> **FILE** constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e.
> included) file. If PHP is running as a
> command-line processor this variable
> contains the script name since PHP
> 4.3.0. Previously it was not available.

#### 'SCRIPT_NAME'

> Contains the current script's path.
> This is useful for pages which need to
> point to themselves. The **FILE**
> constant contains the full path and
> filename of the current (i.e.
> included) file.

#### 'REQUEST_URI'

> The URI which was given in order to
> access this page; for instance,
> '/index.html'