# Difference between: $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] and $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Tags: php

What is the difference between:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']
```

and

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

Thank you.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279966/php-self-vs-path-info-vs-script-name-vs-request-uri

Comment: You may also want to look into the magic constant \_\_FILE__ - http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 12):

They should contain the same information. However, historically and technically speaking, there is a difference between the two.

`SCRIPT_NAME` is defined in the CGI 1.1 specification, and therefore is a standard. This means it should be available no matter what scripting language you're using.

`PHP_SELF` is implemented directly by PHP, and as long as you're programming in PHP, it will be there.

Comment: The name `PHP_SELF` is unique to PHP, but since it is the entire URL path, it is actually a standard defined in IETF, under a different name.

Answer (score 7):

Most of the time it's the same, but `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` is less spoofable than `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, so you should use **SCRIPT_NAME** if you want to reuse that data somewhere on your output.

Check [that article](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/_SERVER_PHP.htm) on different results obtained.

Comment: you should escape output of dynamic data regardless of how spoofable it is.

Comment: @knittl: yes, that's right, reusing it without proper escaping would be a security problem, but it would be far more dangerous with an easily spoofable one.

Comment: Yes, it is more spoofable, but only because it is the entire URL path (obtained after mod_rewrite).  So, it depends what we need. If we need only the SCRIPT_NAME part, then OK, we use that. If we need the entire URL path, we use PHP_SELF and, of course, we should not trust it - it's the URL path.