# what's the difference between PHP_SELF, SCRIPT_NAME and REQUEST_URI in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, global

all is said in the title.

What is the difference between the three properties ? 
I've been testing the value of them and all what I can say is they are similar. However because I'm a standard freak, I'd like to know if there are some subtlety between them so I can avoid bad coding or being stuck later in some unexpected behavior.

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279966/php-self-vs-path-info-vs-script-name-vs-request-uri

Comment: downvoting is not fair, ok i didn't check well if an answer was already posted but just closing seems the proper decision. Indeed the question was not out of the rules of SO.

Answer (score 2):

'PHP_SELF'

The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root. For instance, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a script at the address http://example.com/test.php/foo.bar would be /test.php/foo.bar. The **FILE** constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file. If PHP is running as a command-line processor this variable contains the script name since PHP 4.3.0. Previously it was not available.

'SCRIPT_NAME'

Contains the current script's path. This is useful for pages which need to point to themselves. The **FILE** constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file.

'REQUEST_URI'

The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'.

Comment: I dont understand that negative marking.