# Can PHP access the .htaccess rewrite name of a file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My .htaccess works (not an expert, but do a lot of copy & paste).

A typical rewrite for one of my pages looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^my-grills-parts-and-service/?$ parts-service.php [NC,L]
```

...where the url "http://www.mydomain.com/my-grills-parts-and-service/" will invoke the parts-service.php file.

However, I am using php to construct a fully qualified URL, from what is in the address bar. The problem is, the server variable $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] will return "parts-service.php", rather than what is actually in the address bar, "my-grills-parts-and-service/".

I want php to somehow read the literal rewrite string, rather than the actual filename.

So, I want php to construct a string like this:

```
$url = "http://www.mydomain.com/my-grills-parts-and-service/";
```

I hope I don't have to write a data table or `switch` or `if` block, because that would be doing everything twice (once in the .htaccess, and again in a php file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get real url address.

Before using this method, check @regilero comment.

Comment: Yep. I think this is the answer. I'll give it 24 hours before selecting as best answer. Works great for what I am doing. - G.

Comment: @Gregory Lewis : Beware that you should escape $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] before using to build HTML content, avoid users injection HTML/js in the url. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/326331/550618 for details on SCRIPT_NAME vs REQUEST_URI