# PHP include to highlight active page

Tags: php

I am using this code in a PHP include to give a class to the active page the user is currently browsing.

```
  <li id="nav11">
          <a <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=="contact") echo " class=\"actv\""; ?> href="contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
```

My page is called http://www.domain.com/contact.php

However, nothing happens with my code above.

Comment: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=="contact.php")`

Comment: Have you tried dumping the $_SERVER variable to see what REQUEST_URI is?

Comment: REQUEST_URI must be with forward slash

Comment: Also take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279966/php-self-vs-path-info-vs-script-name-vs-request-uri) to get more informed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <li id="nav11">
      <a <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=="/contact.php") echo " class=\"actv\""; ?> href="contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
```

Have you tried to change "contact" to "/contact.php"?

Comment: I have tried your answer but nothing happens. Do I need to put anything in my htaccess file ?