# using urlrewrite for a domain with parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite `example.com/index.php?post_id=1&seri_id=5` to `example.com/seri-name/post-name`

I found this:

> Store the following in your web roots .htaccess file:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
> ```
>
> In the example above, all URLs are sent on to the index.php scripts.
>   Fetch the URL inside the index.php like this:
>
> ```
> $route = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
> $route = substr($route, strlen('/index.php'));
> ```

but I didn't understand how I can the rewrite process. Can somebody help? Is it the best way to do what I wanted? Is There anything that I can edit to improve it?

Comment: Technically that'd be [PATH_INFO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279966/php-self-vs-path-info-vs-script-name-vs-request-uri).

Comment: Is it the correct way to do what I wanted?