# Current page highlight

Tags: php, html

I'm using php to highlight my current page.

Everything works correctly however when I first go to the page there is nothing after "/" in the domain name.

Ex: mydomain.com/

How can I highlight that page. It only gets highlighted when I have /index.php

Ex: mydomain.com/index.php

Here's my html:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="cd-primary-nav">
      <li><a href="index.php" <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("index")?>>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php" <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("about")?>>About</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.php" <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("services")?>>Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="brands.php" <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("brands")?>>Brands</a></li>
      <li><a href="testimonials.php" <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("testimonials")?>>Reviews</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php" <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("contact" , "thankyou")?>>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
function echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches($requestUri)
{
    $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

    if ($current_file_name == $requestUri)
        echo 'class="selected"';
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using friendly URLs? Check the value of REQUEST_URI in all tests.

Comment: Mike. Yes. I am. The answer below solved it. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use [`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/326331/5113242) to get the executed filename. Even if you browse to `example.com`, it will still contain `index.php` as the value.

Comment: Thank you. This solved it. Also I changed  a href="index.php" to a href="/"