# Image isn't showing up even though path is correct

Tags: php

Right now my file structure looks like this:

```
root
    /images
        /banner.png
    /dir
        /file.php
    /index.php
```

I'm working in `file.php`. I'm trying to access `banner.png`, and so far I have this:

```
<?php echo dirname( dirname(__FILE__) ) . '/' . $recent1["Image"];?>
```

Where `$recent1["Image"]` is `images/banner.jpg`.

When I echo the code as plain text, this path shows up:

```
/home/htdocs/images/banner.png
```

Which I feel like is right, but I'm not sure if it's the exact same thing as

```
(root)/images/banner.png
```

Again, I feel like those two are the same thing, but the image isn't displaying when I put that code I showed above in for the `src` attr for an `img` tag. It shows that broken picture icon thing. Yes, I'm sure that `images/banner.png` exists. Thanks for the help in advance.

Edit: I also might add that in `index.php`, using just `$recent1["Image"]` does indeed display the image.

Comment: The simple answer is if the image does not show the path or filename is probably wrong. However you dont show how this looks in the browser? Use `View Page Source` to see what is getting to the browser

Comment: That path is wrong, because URLs that are sent to the client should start at the web root, not the server's real root. It should be `/images/banner.png`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different [Magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

I think you're looking for

```
__DIR__
```

Using your provided example

```
  <?php echo __DIR__ . '/' . $recent1["Image"];?>
```

Comment: Although I worked around the problem completely, I'm fairly sure this would have fixed it. Good to know for the future, thanks.

Comment: The documentation says **This is equivalent to dirname(__FILE__).**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `__FILE__` you should use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) explains:

> The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root. For instance, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a script at the address http://example.com/foo/bar.php would be /foo/bar.php.

```
<?php echo dirname( dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ) . '/' . $recent1["Image"];?>
```

You could also use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`. They could be different if you have URLs like `/dir/file.php/foo/bar` (this is sometimes preferred for SEO reasons, although it's often rewritten in `.htaccess` to `/dir/file.php?param1=foo&param2=bar`)

You could also use a relative path:

```
<?php echo "../" . $recent1["Image"]; ?>
```

Comment: `PHP_SELF` should not be used, there are far better Magic Constants available as PHP_SELF takes the current value in the browser URL such as `/images/file.php?horse=yes&script=no` would be the value for `PHP_SELF` on this page, when infact something akin to `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` would give the better value of `/images/file.php` (which also can not so easily be adjusted by the visitor editing their own destinaton URL

Comment: Not quite. The query string is not in `PHP_SELF`, it's in `REQUEST_URI`. The only difference between `PHP_SELF` and `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is when you have a URI like `/dir/file.php/foo/bar`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279966/php-self-vs-path-info-vs-script-name-vs-request-uri

Comment: @Martin I've added something about `SCRIPT_FILENAME` to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### The main issue in the code provided is that you are calling `dirname()` twice.

```
<?php echo dirname( dirname(__FILE__) ) . '/' . $recent1["Image"];?>
```

> "Given a string containing the path of a file or directory, this function will return the parent directory's path that is levels up from the current directory."
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

## Example

Given that  `__FILE__` results to `'/home/htdocs/index.php'`.

`dirname(__FILE__)` =`'/home/htdocs/'`

`dirname('/home/htdocs/');`  =`'/home/'`

Then, you append the image path `'/images/banner.jpg'`

#### Results in

```
'home/images/banner.jpg'
```

When the path really should be

```
'/home/htdocs/images/banner.jpg'
```